# Execute JS code before every tag addition to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I am experiencing one issue which I need to handle by adding certain tag to **style** html element.

For this attribute to work I need to target style element, copy it, add new attribute and then remove and add it again to DOM.

Problem is that Angular add style elements dynamically.

So I was wondering if there is some interface where I can hook up before html element is added to DOM and apply attribute I need.

I tried using Mutation Observer but problem is that when I remove and add element again it triggers Mutation observer thus resulting in cycle.

Thanks.

Comment: can you combine your mutation observer with a setTimeout?

Comment: @Spangle Hi. What do you have in mind? I think even when using setTimeout inside Mutation Observer it does not matter if code modifying html element will be executed with timeout cause it will again trigger Mutation Observer.